# Why my flutter app's listview scroll not as smooth as the flutter gallery app?

Tags: android, listview, scroll, dart, flutter

I created a release build of my scroll demo app using Flutter. I wonder why the listview scrolling of my app is NOT as smooth as the flutter gallery app. I used LG G5 for this test.

Here's [a link to my app's demo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzt71EiA6gYLNG9DNFV1OVJJMDA)

**Edit:**
here is the code.

```
class ListViewSample extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext buidContext) {
 return new Container(
  child: new Center(
    child: new ListView(
      children: createListTiles(),
    ),
   )
 );
}

List<Widget> createListTiles() {
 List<Widget> tiles = <Widget>[];
  for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
   int count = i + 1;
   tiles.add(
    new ListTile(
      leading: new CircleAvatar(
        child: new Text("$count"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen[700],
      ),
      title: new Text("Title number $count"),
      subtitle: new Text("This is the subtitle number $count"),
    )
  );
 }
 return tiles;
}
```

Do someone experience the same too?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you implement your ListView? Can you please share some code?

Comment: Did you try release mode？

Answer (score 59):

Flutter is not that smooth with "Debug" build, it runs much smoother with "Release" build ( from command line run "flutter run --release"). Of course Iiro Krankka's answer will also increase the list's performance.

Answer (score 36):

The problem with your code is that you're using the regular `ListView`, which isn't appropriate for lists that have lots of items. All of those 40 widgets are kept in memory, which causes the janky scrolling experience you're suffering from.

If you have a large number or indefinite amount of items, you should be using [ListView.builder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html) instead. It builds only the visible list items on-demand, which makes it possible to have even larger lists scroll smoothly.

Here's a complete sample how you would migrate your list to use the builder approach:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListViewSample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 200,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final count = index + 1;

            return new ListTile(
              leading: new CircleAvatar(
                child: new Text("$count"),
                backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen[700],
              ),
              title: new Text("Title number $count"),
              subtitle: new Text("This is the subtitle number $count"),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note that there's a lot of items, in this case 200, but the scrolling is still buttery smooth.

Comment: @Liro, thank you! I have no idea about this approach. Its like the recyclerview for flutter. I will try this out then accept your answer if i got the smooth scroll I am looking for.

Comment: @Liro I tried your code. It indeed improved the scrolling but still, not as smooth as android native built apps. Is this really expected for flutter?

Comment: Did you try it in debug or release mode? From what I understand, the debug apps use JIT compilation and are a bit slower, hence the "Slow Mode" banner. But release apps are compiled to native code, so they should be generally at least as smooth as native apps, if not better.

Comment: Yes its on release mode. I really thought by running via release mode. I can achieve natove app smoothness.

Comment: How does it perform on the emulator / simulator on debug mode? How about release mode on other devices than LG G5?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply:
I just tested it on emulator and simulator in debug mode. At first, it is not smooth, but around 2 minutes later the scroll feels like native, that's what I want.
I just tested this on galaxy s7 in release mode, the result is the same as my LG g5.

Comment: I tried running it in release mode on a galaxy s4 device with an android 5.0.1 OS. It's buttery smooth!

Comment: Okay, so it seems this might be only related to those two devices. I created an issue about it here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12668

Comment: Hey Kurt, could you tell the exact number of list items that caused the performance issues on LG G5? Also what code did you use to experience the issue? I'm trying to provide more details to the GitHub issue I posted above.

Comment: Hi Liro, 
When I used my own code (the one I posted in the question) the scroll is too slow. I even decrease it to 20 items instead of 40, still slow. 
But when I tried your code, the scroll is better but still, not native enough for me.

Comment: This should definitely not be janky, it looks very simple. One thing to try is to run the app in profile mode and look at the event trace in the observatory, it will show you where the time is going. Maybe there's something else in your app that's unexpectedly interfering?

Comment: Hi Ian, I'm not really familiar with the observatory. Where in the observatory will I look for unnecessary processing? Thanks

Comment: Btw, it runs natively smooth on HTC one M9 marshmallow.

Answer (score 9):

First, you should always try to use `ListView.builder` whenever possible.

Second, you should set `resamplingEnabled` flag if the problem occurs on devices that support a higher refresh rate for the input than the display itself. For example, the Pixel 4 input runs at 120 Hz while the display runs at 90 Hz. This mismatch can cause slow scrolling performance.

```
void main() {
  GestureBinding.instance.resamplingEnabled = true; // Set this flag. 
  run(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Hey can you provide any documentation or article for this?

Comment: @AmberK You can find it [here](https://medium.com/flutter/announcing-flutter-1-22-44f146009e5f).

Comment: Getting exception while running this line "Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The setter 'resamplingEnabled=' was called on null" @CopsOnRoad

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use ListView.builder, because you need to have different widgets in a ListView, you can use Column wrapped in SingleChildScrollView, instead of a ListView, like this:

```
class ListViewSample extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext buidContext) {
 return new Container(
  child: new Center(
    child: new SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column()
        children: <Widget>[
           headerWidget(context: context, step: 'STEP 1', text: "Company data"),
           MyTextFieldWidget(
              type: prefix0.TextFieldType.Text,
              labelText: 'Insured',
              prefsKey: COMPANY_INSURED,
              editable: false,
           ),
           MyTextFieldWidget(
              type: prefix0.TextFieldType.Text,
              labelText: 'Address 1',
              prefsKey: COMPANY_INSURED,
              editable: false,
           ),
           MyTextFieldWidget(
              type: prefix0.TextFieldType.Text,
              labelText: 'Address 2',
              prefsKey: COMPANY_INSURED,
              editable: false,
           ),
        ],)
    ),
   )
 );
}
```

This also will fix the scrolling behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `itemExtent: 2000,` (2000 here is example length of your list) using this the scrolling machinery can make use of the foreknowledge of the children's extent to save work.
Many people suggested that release mode will fix the issue but that's wrong. It shouldn't be. On a low performance phone I faced lagging of list view under 4 tabs.

Comment: The value of itemExtent is NOT the length of your list.  It's the height of each list item.  Providing it does definitely allow your list to scroll faster though.  Because then flutter doesn't have to lookup the list item height for each item.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter’s profile mode compiles and launches your application almost identically to release mode, but with just enough additional functionality to allow debugging performance problems. For example, profile mode provides tracing information to the profiling tools.

In Android Studio and IntelliJ, use the Run > Flutter Run main.dart in Profile Mode menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it using flutter run --release it solved my problem